# similar command to get the functionality of quote in OS400/AS400 while using ftplib

Tags: python, ibm-midrange, mainframe, ftplib

We have an OS400 server trying to run below command to convert ascii file to normal readable file

```
command : quote rcmd cpytoimpf fromfile(abc/hhgghh) tostmf('/temp/test1002') mbropt(*add) stmfcodpag(*pcascii) rcddlm(*crlf)
```

using quote command getting below error

```
500 Subcommand QUOT not valid
```

We are trying to connect to this os400 using ftplib and using sendcmd to run a command : as we trying to remote login most of the commands are  not valid and unable to achieve the same functionality of the above quote command

can any one please help..

Comment: Consider asking the developer of ftplib.

Comment: quote is a command that runs on the client side if the client is an IBM i, it sends a command rcmd... to the connected server that will run the cpyfrmimpf command. I don't know about ftplib, but the way you use it here is probably the equivalent of using quote, so you just have to send everything but quote

Comment: The OS/400 FTP _server_ is probably what you need to understand here. The FTP protocol has a number of convenience features which may or may not be supported by individual FTP servers, and then what the support looks like tends to be OS-dependent.